# Синонимизировать и объединить [postgresql] и [postgres]

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

[postgres](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/postgres) - это историческое название проекта времён проекта университета Беркли. Затем мутировало в [postgresql](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/postgresql), но [postgres](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/postgres) всё так же является допустимым наименованием, особенно если не уверены как [postgresql](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/postgresql) произносится в устной речи ([FAQ в вики](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/FAQ#What_is_PostgreSQL.3F_How_is_it_pronounced.3F_What_is_Postgres.3F) проекта).

На ruSO с тегом [postgres](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/postgres) сейчас всего 12 вопросов.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Синонимизировал и объединил. Кеш в ближайшее время обновится.